# mysql_insert_id() returns 0 rarely

Tags: php, mysql

I am maintaining a server that runs for around 1 year. Nothings gonna be wrong previously. However, suddenly, there is an error in mysql_insert_id(), which returns 0, instead of normal row id from the database. Here's are the core of the code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table (name,email) VALUES('$name','$email')";

mysql_query($sql);

$current = mysql_insert_id();
```

Also notice that even if there are no changes in the code, the program runs smoothly again after the error has happened. It seems strange to me.

Here is my possible explanation. Since I am hosting in a public server, where many are using the same MYSQL server. Will it be that when `mysql_query($sql)`, the server then swap the process and let another guy to run another SQL command, which may be for example, a `SELECT` statement, and after their execution, it swaps back to my own code and continue executing, which results in 0?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: butter way to do is, use parameter and transaction based query using PDO to get rid of this situation.

Comment: this is php question please tag as a php

Comment: My boss told me not to change as much things as possible, and just solve the problems here. Since there are thousands of pages with such kinds of settings. And only one page temporarily dies like this.

Answer (score 2):

to be sure use the resource_identifier as parameter in mysql_queryand mysql_insert_id.
If you don't, the last connection to the mysql server is used, as you thought.

```
$resource = mysql_connect(...);
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table (name,email) VALUES('$name','$email')";

mysql_query($sql, $resource);

$current = mysql_insert_id($resource);
```

Please consider using mysqli oder PDO since mysql_* functions are deprecated and are going to be removed in future PHP-Versions

Comment: I understand that... MySQL is removed in PHP 7.0 already. If I do not remember wrongly. However, since I am helping my boss to maintain the system and I am being ordered to find out the problem of this case, but not changing the code. :(

Comment: the problem is the ressource_identifier.
You can not solve the problem without the ressource_identifier since this is a code error and not a server fault.

Comment: do you mean that the error comes from what I am thinking of? Therefore, I should supply $link_identifier as in `int mysql_insert_id ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`. And the problem will then be solved?

Comment: yes, i think you have been right. If someone is creating a new mysql instance in the timespan between your mysql_connect and the mysql_insert_id you will be using the new opened ressource, which maybe has not inserted an dataset, though it will return 0